Is there a reasonably up-to-date (as of early 2020s) review article on the Sleeping Beauty problem?
EDIT: I apologise for the lack of detail and clarity in the original post; I hope that my newly edited version will be clearer, and I particularly thank Conifold for useful feedback in the comments.

CONTEXT.
I am a mathematician, and I am hoping to write a paper on the Sleeping Beauty problem, in which I seek to refute the 'thirder' position and argue that either the answer is 1/2 or there simply is no numerical value for SB's credance. (I also want to argue against any notion that 'in one sense the correct answer is 1/2 and in another sense the correct answer is 1/3'.)
I am familiar with some of the standard arguments in favour of the thirder position, e.g.:

a frequentist argument [if the experiment were run lots of times, one third of her wakings would be Heads];
an argument from arithmetic with conditional probabilities [the equations P(H|Mon)=P(T|Mon) and P(Mon|T)=P(Tue|T) imply the conclusion];
I've also encountered in YouTube comments an 'updated-probabilities' argument [the act of waking is an acquiring of new information ruling out everything except (Mon,H), (Mon,T) and (Tue,T) from a sample space {Days}x{H,T} whose prior probability distribution is uniform], although I don't know if there's academic literature with this type of argument.

I'm also familiar with "extreme variants" like: 1,000,000 days instead of 2 days for Tails; and the combination of that with a 1000:1 bias of the coin in favour of Heads.
My intended logical structure is to argue that

the reason for ongoing contention is that, unlike the Monty Hall Problem or the Boy Or Girl Paradox, there is no way to "prove" the answer one way or another in terms of the established rigorous mathematical framework of probability theory;
in particular, the reason why the thirder position persists - despite the intuitive absurdity of the conclusions when applying the same arguments to some of the extreme scenarios - is that the thirder arguments often have a misleading air of apparent mathematical rigour;
the standard arguments in favour of the thirder position are all based on either probability fallacies, inadequately justified assumptions, or a misunderstanding of how to correctly interpret the mathematical formalism of sample spaces;
the case in favour of the halfer position is extremely potent, even if it can't directly be expressed within the established rigorous framework of probability theory.

MY QUESTION.
It obviously wouldn't be very good if my paper has glaring omissions of reference to some relevant important existing work on the Sleeping Beauty problem.
But on the other hand, I expect that there are hundreds on papers on the Sleeping Beauty problem, and I probably wouldn't have the time to try and read through and understand them all.
So my question is: Are there a handful of papers that together summarise a sufficient breadth of the major academic contributions to the SB problem for me to be able to place my contribution in adequate context by reading those papers?

I see that someone downvoted this question - would anyone be able to provide me with feedback as to likely reasons why this question might have been downvoted? Thanks.

Not me, but people here usually expect more context to such requests. What specifically about the problem interests you, why recent is important, etc. It helps with narrowing down relevant references. "Summarises most or all of the most important academic contributions" is vague and typically non-existent.

@Conifold Thank you, this is interesting, especially the "typically non-existent" bit. I wonder if this is a difference between philosophy and mathematics - I am a mathematician, and I suspect (though I might be wrong) that if I asked for a review paper summarising most or all of the important contributions so far towards solving some maths problem like existence of infinite-time solutions of the Navier-Stokes equations, this would not be a problem.

@JulianNewman I'm thinking the problem is that despite our high tolerance for mathematical content on this site (Foundations questions are an important part of philosophy), you are asking for a summary of mathematical literature regarding a mathematical problem. Now, that you are looking at the proof-theoretic foundations of the literature makes the problem entirely philosophical, but many members tend to see the shallow aspects of the question, mathematical literature. So since it's been closed check out https://plato.stanford.edu/search/search?query=%22sleeping+beauty+problem%22

If I were you, I'd do your homework, and come back and instead of a reference request for mathematical literature, I'd ask specific philosophical questions like how [Bayesian Epistemology (SEP)[https://plato.stanford.edu/search/search?query=%22sleeping+beauty+problem%22] for instance relates to X or how Interpretation of Probability of Y affects proof. Something along those lines.

@JD Thank you - but all of the discussion and controversy over the Sleeping Beauty problem is over philosophical considerations, not over how to do the mathematics after one has determined from philosophy how to set up the problem as a purely mathematics problem. As far as I'm aware, the Sleeping Beauty problem is generally classed as a philosophy question; e.g. I don't think any Pure Mathematics journal would accept papers about the Sleeping Beauty problem, unless the paper developed an approach that involved mathematics which is of interest in its own right.

All of the points you make in the bullets list appear to be references to probability theory, not to philosophical questions.  I am not following why this is not a math question.  What are the philosophy questions?

@Dcleve Thank you for your comment. 'Probability theory' as a mathematics discipline - i.e., what we could call the mathematics of probability - concerns questions of (broadly speaking) the form, "What conclusions result from such-and-such pure-mathematical framing of such-and-such non-determined scenario?" The question of how to actually decide upon a mathematical framing of a non-determined scenario is not a mathematics question - the validity of a proposed solution is not determined by mathematical proof, but is rooted in philosophical notions, e.g. epistemology, credance, etc.

@JulianNewman -- I don't think I agree with you on that point.  At my college, probability (which at the time was entirely frequentist) was taught in the math department, and frequentist probability uses a LOT of approximations and rules of thumb to get to useful outcomes.  That is the Bayesian critique of frequentism.  BUT, once math accepted that math is infinite, THEN what math to use in our world was always going to be a pragmatic/empirical question.  The philosophy discussion is over at that point!  After that you are just into math-application-specific pragmatism.

@Dcleve "The question of how to actually decide upon a mathematical framing of a non-determined scenario is not a mathematics question - the validity of a proposed solution is not determined by mathematical proof, but is rooted in philosophical notions" This is a solid claim. Specifically, it's a metaphysical claim to choose from and among different theories of probability and causality, whether one has a realist or nominalist bent. If the SBP is essentially one of choosing a set of relevant metaphysical presuppositions to handle probability, the problem is ineluctably philosophy of math.

I added "sleeping-beauty-problem" and "philosophy-of-mathematics " as tags, because it seems to be quite an open debate among mathematicians interested in the topic.

I did some cursory searching. Looks like you found a gap in the literature. You should do a review paper yourself and come back and update my post to include it! Good luck.

There are hundreds of matches to "Sleeping Beauty" on philpapers.org.
For some review papers, you could try the following:

Randall McCutcheon (2014) This is the end, Beautiful friend
Peter Winkler (2017) The Sleeping Beauty Controversy
Michael G. Titelbaum (2013)  Ten Reasons to Care About the Sleeping Beauty Problem

For a couple of recent defences of the thirder position, have a look at these:

Lennart Ackermans (2024) Sleeping Beauty: Why Everyone Should Be a Thirder
Tim Button, Daniel Rothschild, Levi Spectre (2024)  Too clever by halving


I would be surprised if you could find a better general summary than this paper from 2017:  https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/sb.pdf Maybe something insightful has been published since 2017 to add to this list. However, I think you will have to do your own research to see, as we don't seem to have any fans of the problem here on site.
This recent takedown of analytic philosophy and its pointless abstract questions is one that I at least tend to support in principle:   https://bobhannahbob1.medium.com/the-sleeping-beauty-problem-how-analytic-philosophy-generates-unsolvable-puzzles-cdf5ecee8bb0  However it is not an academic paper, and more of a venting blog.  Also, while I agree with its general sentiment about the problems with analytic philosophy, I disagree with its conclusion.  This problem is solvable, and the reason that it appears not to be, is a result of analytic philosophers not realizing what reference frames they need to adopt to solve particular pragmatic problems.
As I noted above, this is a solvable problem if one keeps close track of what one is trying to evaluate, and that is something the philosophers here, who appear not to include many scientists or philosophers of science, seem to regularly lose track of.  They mostly seem to have stopped reading philosophy of science with Hume!
What one should do with the problem is treat it as a science question, using indirect realism, conjectures and refutations.  I.E. Popperian science.
What day it is when sleeping beauty wakes up, is not relevant to the coin flip.  The grid of 3 observations, or four possibilities of observation, is irrelevant to that question.  We have a theory, that the coin is fair, and no reason whatsoever to question that.  In fact, the coin fairness is treated as uncontestable in the question.  Note therefore, there is no test, or additional evidence, relative to the coin's fairness.  Given the coin fairness, the probability of a heads flip is 50%, the halfer position.
What IS being tested, is what day it is when SB wakes up.  The philosophers who are confused here, keep confusing this question with the coin flip question.  When asked whether it is Tuesday or Monday, SB's answer should be the thirder position.  There are three possible wake up events, two on Monday, and one on Tuesday, so Tuesday should have a 1/3 credence. The bizarre "double halfer" position that it should be only 1/4 credence for Tuesday -- is just an indication of how confused these analytic thinkers are!
I did not see this response in the 2017 summary.  Maybe you will find it articulated somewhere in the lit on the subject.
Addendum.  The different answer I gave to this different version of the question is, I believe, critical to understanding where the confusion here is.  Does the halfer position in the Sleeping Beauty problem make for an irrational gambler?
The coin is halfer, but the observations are a deliberately skewed sampling set, so they are not representative of "reality" and are thirder.
I would expect the statistics of sampling bias to be well within the realm of what you can definitively characterize, so you should be able to settle this pseudo-conundrum with a good paper!

So, after poking around, I would have to say if there is a review article or book, it's effaced from the search process.

Wikipedia's bibliography cleverly includes a reference to PhilPapers but it's the search doesn't seem to have much listed that qualifies as "review". Here's a work by Marc Burock added in 2023 that conducts a review of multiple arguments. An article by Jeffrey Sanford Russell from 2024 seems to address the question from evidentiary theory, and is likely a review of ideas since it's in a Routledge Handbook.
A Google scholar search for "sleeping beauty problem" and review set to "since 2020" doesn't seem to turn up much of anything regarding some sort of anthology of material.
Britannica and the IEP turn up nothing.
The SEP has a number of articles where the phrase is included but seemingly not covered in any depth. In fact, it looks to be covered by bibliographic entries such as Lewis and Bostrom's work related to the topic.
I did a search on this site and while lots of SBP articles float to the top, a quick scan of the first few didn't turn up any "review" materials.
arXiv has 17 potential leads and one that might meet your needs is Piva and Ruffolo's "Revisiting the Sleeping Beauty Problem". The abstract says:


The Sleeping Beauty problem is a probability riddle with no definite solution for more than two decades and its solution is of great interest in many fields of knowledge. There are two main competing solutions to the problem: the halfer approach, and the thirder approach. The main reason for disagreement in the literature is connected to the use of different probability spaces to represent the same probabilistic riddle. In this work, we analyse the problem from a mathematical perspective, identifying probability distributions induced directly from the thought experiment's rules. The precise choices of probability spaces provide both halfer and thirder solutions to the problem. To try and decide on which approach to follow, a criterion involving the information available to Sleeping Beauty is proposed. (emphasis mine)

Unlike most of the other papers, this one seems to propose desidirata and criteria to choose among solutions, as opposed to arguing a single definitive solution. That would necessitate some measure of review of major approaches. Sorry can't be more of a help, but philosophy of probability is not my jam. Good luck!

@Dcleve Thanks!!!
